# How to change 3rd field of numbers to text?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a format looking like this:

```
983243 woiewewrsadhjf 234
093111 srewdslkjfdgdsdsf 111
```

Can i use sed to search for all instances of text in the third field and change only those while leaving other third fields as is?
So searching for 111 in the third field, changing all third fields containing 111 into othertext, wile leaving other third fields (such as 234) as they are.

If possible can you guys break down the solution so I can get educated on how the command is formed. I am here to learn.

Comment: Any time you find yourself mentioning a "field" you should be using awk, not sed or grep, since awk is the tool that is designed to operate on fields within records.

Comment: Could you share with us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be `sed`, here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '$3=="111"{$3="othertext"}1' input.txt
```

This will, for every line, look if the third field (recognized by default as space-separated group of characters) equals `111` and if so, set it to `othertext` instead. If your input data uses a different separator (say `TAB`), you have to specify that using the `-F` command-line option (e.g. `awk -F'\t' '....'`).

The `1` outside the rule block `{ ... }` (or actually any condition evaluating to "true"/non-zero) instructs `awk` to print the current line, including all modifications made. That way, lines that do not require changing will be printed "as is".

One caveat: `awk` will re-assemble those lines that needed changing from the individual fields, using the "output field separator" internally stored as variable `OFS`, which defaults to a single space. This is usually no problem, but if your columns are separated by more than one space, these separators will (by default) be interpreted as only *one single* input separator, so these lines will appear with changed field separation on output.

Answer (score 1):

The way to handle fields in `sed` is as shown. First we mark out the third nonspace chunk by fencing it with a char known not to be present in the pattern space, viz., the record separator, `\n`. Then if the substitution succeeded => there was a 111 in the third field. Else we remove the newlines.

We are using `GNU sed` with extended regex flag `-E` turned on.

```
$ sed -Ee '
    s/\S+/\n&\n/3
    s/\n111\n/otherwise/
    s/\n//g
' file
```

Posixly we do like this:

```
$ sed -e '
    s/[^[:space:]]\{1,\}/\
&\
/3
    s/\n111\n/otherwise/
    s/\n//g
' file
```

Answer (score -1):

`echo '093111 srewdslkjfdgdsdsf 111' | sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(111\)/\1 \2 othertext/'`

This does what you want.

Just be aware that the text you are searching (111 in this case) does not contain special characters, like `\`, `.` or `*`. They need to be escaped in this case.

**Explanation**

The `.` matches any character.

`*` means zero or more repetitions of the previous atom.

Hence, when we write `.*` we will match any sequence of characters. In most situations sed is greedy, meaning that it will try to match the biggest sequence it can. But since we are requiring that the next character is a space, the `.*` will finish the match when it finds it.

With Basic Regular Expressions (default in sed) we can use `\(` and `\)` to separate different atoms. We use them to mark 3 atoms.

In the second part of the command, `\n` means 'the atom at position n'. We are using the first and the second, but we replace the third by any text we need.

Note: when working with fields (separated by white spaces) it is normally easier to work with awk:

`echo '093111 srewdslkjfdgdsdsf 111' | awk '{if ($3 == "111") $3 = "othertext"; print}'`